Unable to make an http request using curl in a shell script
I have a shell script function that takes a url and some arguments. The function then constructs a curl request and executes it. However I get an error.
This is my function:
function sendWithRetry() {

    local _URL="$1"
    local _CURL_ARGS="${@:2}"
    RESPONSE=""
    for x in {0..20} ;
    do
        
        echo "Sending request to $_URL"
        cat ${CALLBACK_REQUEST_IPV4_HTTPS}
        echo "Executing : curl --connect-timeout 1 -f -s ${_CURL_ARGS} $_URL "
        RESPONSE=$(curl --connect-timeout 1 -f -s ${_CURL_ARGS} $_URL) && break

    done

    if [ $x -lt 20 ] ;
    then
        echo "Request $_URL sent successfully!!!"
        echo "Response: $RESPONSE"
    else
        echo "Failed to send request to $_URL!!!"
        exit 1
    fi
}

The following is the code snippet that calls the sendWithRetry function
if ! sendWithRetry "${TEST_URL_HTTPS}" -k -X POST -H '"Content-Type: application/json"' -d @${CALLBACK_REQUEST_IPV4_HTTPS}
then
    echo "Test failed!!!"
    exit 1
fi

However I get the that the url returned 404 . i am not sure what is the issue. i suspect if it is due to the way i pass arguments to my function.
[INFO]      [exec] # $$ echo "Sending request to $_URL"
[INFO]      [exec] # Sending request to https://192.168.16.5:31444/service-b/v1/subscribe?p2=test
[INFO]      [exec] # $$ cat ${CALLBACK_REQUEST_IPV4_HTTPS}
[INFO]      [exec] # {
[INFO]      [exec] #     "testname": "service-b makes a callback request to service-a over IPv4 & HTTPS protocol",
[INFO]      [exec] #     "Uri": "https://192.168.16.5:30443/callback/service-b/v1/handleNotify",
[INFO]      [exec] #     "p3": "param-3",
[INFO]      [exec] #     "p5": "param-5"
[INFO]      [exec] # }$$ echo "Executing : curl --connect-timeout 1 -f  ${_CURL_ARGS} $_URL "
[INFO]      [exec] # Executing : curl --connect-timeout 1 -f  -v -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @/test/scripts/tests/dual-stack/callback-flow/callbackRequestIpv4Https.json https://192.168.16.5:31444/service-b/v1/subscribe?p2=test
[INFO]      [exec] # $$ RESPONSE=$(curl --connect-timeout 1 -f -s ${_CURL_ARGS} $_URL)
[INFO]      [exec] # $$ curl --connect-timeout 1 -f -s ${_CURL_ARGS} $_URL
[INFO]      [exec] # * Could not resolve host: application
[INFO]      [exec] # * Closing connection
[INFO]      [exec] # *   Trying 192.168.16.5:31444...
[INFO]      [exec] # * Connected to 192.168.16.5 (192.168.16.5) port 31444
[INFO]      [exec] # * ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
[INFO]      [exec] # } [5 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
[INFO]      [exec] # } [512 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
[INFO]      [exec] # { [122 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
[INFO]      [exec] # { [15 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
[INFO]      [exec] # { [83 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
[INFO]      [exec] # { [670 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
[INFO]      [exec] # { [264 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
[INFO]      [exec] # { [52 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
[INFO]      [exec] # } [1 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
[INFO]      [exec] # } [8 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
[INFO]      [exec] # } [52 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 / x25519 / RSASSA-PSS
[INFO]      [exec] # * ALPN: server accepted h2
[INFO]      [exec] # * Server certificate:
[INFO]      [exec] # *  subject: O=Openet; CN=Ingress for svc-b-ingress
[INFO]      [exec] # *  start date: Oct 14 08:30:17 2024 GMT
[INFO]      [exec] # *  expire date: Apr 12 08:30:17 2025 GMT
[INFO]      [exec] # *  issuer: O=Openet; CN=Openet Test CA
[INFO]      [exec] # *  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
[INFO]      [exec] # *   Certificate level 0: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using ecdsa-with-SHA256
[INFO]      [exec] # } [5 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * using HTTP/2
[INFO]      [exec] # * [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://192.168.16.5:31444/service-b/v1/subscribe?p2=test
[INFO]      [exec] # * [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: POST]
[INFO]      [exec] # * [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
[INFO]      [exec] # * [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: 192.168.16.5:31444]
[INFO]      [exec] # * [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /service-b/v1/subscribe?p2=test]
[INFO]      [exec] # * [HTTP/2] [1] [user-agent: curl/8.8.0]
[INFO]      [exec] # * [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: */*]
[INFO]      [exec] # * [HTTP/2] [1] [content-length: 209]
[INFO]      [exec] # * [HTTP/2] [1] [content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
[INFO]      [exec] # } [5 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # > POST /service-b/v1/subscribe?p2=test HTTP/2
[INFO]      [exec] # > Host: 192.168.16.5:31444
[INFO]      [exec] # > User-Agent: curl/8.8.0
[INFO]      [exec] # > Accept: */*
[INFO]      [exec] # > Content-Length: 209
[INFO]      [exec] # > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
[INFO]      [exec] # >
[INFO]      [exec] # } [209 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * upload completely sent off: 209 bytes
[INFO]      [exec] # { [5 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
[INFO]      [exec] # { [230 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
[INFO]      [exec] # { [230 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # * old SSL session ID is stale, removing
[INFO]      [exec] # { [5 bytes data]
[INFO]      [exec] # < HTTP/2 404
[INFO]      [exec] # < content-type: application/problem+json
[INFO]      [exec] # < 3gpp-sbi-message-priority: 24
[INFO]      [exec] # < content-length: 37
[INFO]      [exec] # < x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1
[INFO]      [exec] # < date: Mon, 14 Oct 2024 15:05:10 GMT
[INFO]      [exec] # < server: PCF-91fd8c65-677a-4292-9333-376ba9649ffd
[INFO]      [exec] # <
[INFO]      [exec] # * The requested URL returned error: 404

appreciate any help
thank you

Do you get the 404 error when you type the intended curl command in by hand? Also, please explain where the log file comes from, since it looks like curl was run with the --verbose flag there, but I don't see that flag anywhere in the code you provided. Your bottom code snippet is also not valid shell script, so it would help if you could update that, for clarity.

i tried it manally and i didnt get 404

Make $_CURL_ARGS an array, not a string. And you shouldn't have nested quotes in the -H argument.

@Barmar has given you some clues, and the accepted answer in the linked question is helpful, but I regret not having a go at answering your question before it was closed. To go a bit further, it's possible to robustly parse arguments to a script or a function in Bash, with a while loop and an array, and avoid these quoting problems. Just make sure that you use the "${arrayname[@]}" form when unpacking the arguments, so that each one in the array is quoted individually, preserving interior whitespace. See also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

The evidence that you have a quoting problem is the error message Could not resolve host: application in your log output. That indicates that the argument to the -H option wasn't quoted properly, in spite of your (valiant) efforts at compensating for that with extra layers of quotes when you called the function.
